# Are there any tricks to avoid having to urlencode a url in a querystring

Tags: php, query-string, urlencode

I'm trying to put a script together for a client that needs to be able to accept a web address in a query string without it first being urlencoded. An example would be like this:

http://foo.com/script.php?url=www.amazon.co.uk/ESET-Smart-Security-User-Year/dp/B005NPFOBM/ref=sr_1_1?s=software&ie=UTF8&qid=1341685530&sr=1-1

However, when I echo out the contents of $_GET['url'] it gives me the following:

www.amazon.co.uk/ESET-Smart-Security-User-Year/dp/B005NPFOBM/ref=sr_1_1?s=software

So basically it seems to choke on the first ampersand - i'm guessing because it thinks that its another variable.

Aside form urlencoding, are there any tricks to getting this working? I could probably POST it from a form, but this defeats the idea of the script.

Comment: no. with GET requests, encoding the url ist the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific use case, you should use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` instead. This will give you the full query string in one go, you can then split it yourself.

In your example, PHP is assuming that the & is the delimiter for the next GET variable.

Comment: Simple, yet genius. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you could ask the query parameters, and add them to the URL you received. List the remaining parameters in $_GET in the proper order, and add them add the end of $_GET['url'].

```
$_GET['url']
 + '&ie=' + $_GET['ie']
 + '&qid=' + $_GET['qid']
 + '&sr=' + $_GET['sr']
```

Be careful that you might get an extra parameter url someday.
http://foo.com/script.php?url=www.amazon.co.uk/ESET-Smart-Security-User-Year/dp/B005NPFOBM/ref=sr_1_1?s=software&ie=UTF8&qid=1341685530&sr=1-1&url=http://someAmazoneStuff